# PHP - how do I return JSON in a specific format I need?

Tags: php, json

I have a PHP file which currently returns JSON in these two ways:

If an error happens, I do this:

```
$post_data = array('error' => "no_member_id");
echo json_encode($post_data);
```

and if there is no error, and I need to return data in JSON format, I do this:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0 )
{
         $rows = array();
         while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
         {
             $rows[] = $r;
         }

         echo json_encode($rows);
}
```

But what I really need to do is return the data in a format like this:

```
{"result":"ok", data :[{"data1":"value1", "data2":"value2"}]}
```

or this:

```
{"result":"error", data :[{"error":"no_id"}]}
```

Could someone please help me understand how to do that?

Thanks!!

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk thank you. How long do you think I have before these statements stop working in my code? :)

Comment: I don't think it matters; you should switch as soon as possible.

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk of course timing matters. I can't just rewrite all my code ASAP.  I am curious how much time I realistically have.

Comment: When PHP 5.5 is released and used, you will get an [`E_DEPRECATED`](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php) notice.

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk but the code won't stop working, right? It will just be a notice to change my code?

Comment: You can suppress the notices; but I don't know what type of nudge you need to start changing ***now***.

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk thank you for your help. Changing is a business decision depending on how big the danger is. So I am trying to assess the danger :) and how long I have to change it :)

Comment: It's actually not a business decision when it becomes a technical requirement.

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk everything is a business decision, and technology decisions stem out of what the business needs :)

Comment: Not according to project management.

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk LOL I am guessing we can go on like this for a while :)

Answer (score 2):

```
echo json_encode( array( "result" => "ok", "data" => $rows ) );
```

instead of

```
echo json_encode($rows);
```

Answer (score 1):

first, stop using mysql built in functions. they will be deprecated.

try this:

```
$result = 0;
$json = array(
 'result' => 'ok',
 'data'   => array()  
);
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0 )
  while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $json['data'][] = $r;
  }
} else {
  $json['result'] = 'error';
  $json['data'] = array('error' => "no_member_id");
}
echo json_encode($json);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add result key with specific value  in both array:

```
echo json_encode(array("result" => "ok", "data" : $rows));
```

and

```
echo json_encode(array("result" => "error", "data" : $post_data));
```